# d3js - How to plot a multi line chart chart for multiple groups of items that can be updated?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am a very new beginner to d3 and have currently got a simple line chart working displaying two lines for some data for a single group. What I would like to do is be able to create multiple lines for multiple groups in a flexible way. Each group would have several lines and they would be colour coded for the group parent - in my data in this case it's asset or stock ticker

Currently you can see in my code I am manually creating an array for each path but i guess this could get really messy if i start to have 100's of paths. Is there a better way to do this?

I've tried to use d3.nest but i just cannot for the life of me figure how the data should be so can apply the update/enter/exit pattern for each group of lines

Here is my WIP code:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="graphDiv"></div>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var data_set = [{
    'Date': '2009-03-23',
    'Raw': 25,
    'Raw2': 25,
    'Asset': 'A'
  },
  {
    'Date': '2009-03-24',
    'Raw': 28,
    'Raw2': 25.4,
    'Asset': 'A'
  },
  {
    'Date': '2009-03-25',
    'Raw': 26,
    'Raw2': 25.37,
    'Asset': 'B'
  },
  {
    'Date': '2009-03-26',
    'Raw': 22,
    'Raw2': 25.03,
    'Asset': 'B'
  },
  {
    'Date': '2009-03-27',
    'Raw': 19,
    'Raw2': 24.42,
    'Asset': 'C'
  },
  {
    'Date': '2009-03-28',
    'Raw': 23,
    'Raw2': 24.28,
    'Asset': 'D'
  }
]

var margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
};
var svgWidth = 600;
var svgHeight = 1000;
var graphWidth = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var graphHeight = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y");
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, graphWidth]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([graphHeight, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10); // for colours
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x).ticks(10);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y).ticks(10);

// Need to create the lines manually for each bit of data
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.y);
  });

// Creates the SVG area within the div on the dom 
// Just doing this once 
var svg = d3.select("#graphDiv")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgWidth)
  .attr("height", svgHeight)
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
    svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
  }));

// Add the X Axis
g.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + graphHeight + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
// Text label for x axis 
g.append("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("timeseries dates")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (graphWidth / 2) + " ," + (graphHeight + margin.top) + ")");

// Add the Y Axis
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
// text label for the y axis
g.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
  .attr("x", 0 - (graphHeight / 2))
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("price points");


function drawGraph(data_set) {

  let pathData = []
  //assume 2 paths
  pathData.push([])
  pathData.push([])

  // Pass in the data here 
  data_set.forEach(function(d) {

    let path0 = {}
    let path1 = {}

    path0.date = parseDate(d.Date)
    path1.date = parseDate(d.Date)

    path0.y = +d.Raw
    path1.y = +d.Raw2

    pathData[0].push(path0)
    pathData[1].push(path1)

  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data_set, function(d) {
    return parseDate(d.Date);
  }));
  y.domain([
    d3.min(data_set, function(d) {
      return Math.min(d.Raw, d.Raw2)
    }),
    d3.max(data_set, function(d) {
      return Math.max(d.Raw, d.Raw2)
    })
  ]);

  var lines = g.selectAll(".path")
    .data(pathData)

  lines.exit().remove()

  var enter = lines.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "path")
    .style("stroke", (d, i) => z(i))

  var merge = enter.merge(lines)
    .attr("d", line)

}

// display initial chart
window.onload = drawGraph(data_set)
// Push new data every 5 seconds for a specific date
var h = setInterval(function() {
  data_set.push({
    'Date': '2009-03-29',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  }, {
    'Date': '2009-03-30',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  }, {
    'Date': '2009-03-31',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  }, {
    'Date': '2009-04-01',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  }, {
    'Date': '2009-04-02',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  }, {
    'Date': '2009-04-03',
    'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
    'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
    'Asset': 'A'
  });
  drawGraph(data_set);
}, 5000);
</script>
</body>```
````

Comment: So if I understand correctly for each date, you have two lines represented by numbers in `Raw` and `Raw2` keys? And you have a data_set to start with but then new data with more dates will come in and you want the chart to update accordingly?

Comment: HI @Coola, many thanks for taking the time to reply. Yes partially correct, what I want is for there to be two lines to represent Raw and Raw2 values but there could be several groups i.e assets! so if there is asset A and asset B, there will be 4 lines, 2 for each asset. Ideally they should be colour coordinated too! So I'm looking for a way to plot this and have it all being able to be updated

Comment: The code below resolves the issue of clutter. However what you are talking about, is more to do in the nature in which the data binding occurs. Currently you are plotting only 2 lines for Asset A (Raw) and Asset B (Raw2)? Your data structure in the problem does not have data for 4 separate lines. So you will need to update your data to account for 4 lines for me to be able to solve that.

Comment: Hi @Coola, all the data is already present within the data_set - are you able to assist with that or should I ask another question? 
Many thanks for clearing up the cluttered code :)

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding the use case? Are you going to have 100s of `Raw` data? or 100s of dates for which you have data for 2 `Raw`s?

Comment: There will be lots of assets for many dates each with a raw and raw2 value. I need to create and have lines updated for every raw and raw2 value for each asset @Coola

Comment: And with respect to colors do you want them to be colored by assets or by Raw and Raw2?

Comment: @Coola By asset first but then raw and raw2 would have some slight difference in colour to see the difference between them - hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues in your code:

1. You were not updating your axis. As a result your x-Axis was showing dates in January, 2000 instead of your dates of 2009-March / April. To fix this, you have to update your axis in the `drawGraph` function as:

   ```
   svg.selectAll('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
   svg.selectAll('.y.axis').call(yAxis);
   ```
2. Your test using `setInterval` keeps sending data with the same dates over and over again after the first iteration of the loop. As a result your `data_set` passes the data for the same dates into your `pathData`. To fix this the test would be better built as:

   ```
   let newdata = [{
     'Date': '2009-03-29',
     'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
     'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
     'Asset': 'A'
   }, {
     'Date': '2009-03-30',
     'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
     'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
     'Asset': 'A'
   }, {
     'Date': '2009-03-31',
     'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
     'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
     'Asset': 'A'
   }, {
     'Date': '2009-04-01',
     'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
     'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
     'Asset': 'A'
   }, {
     'Date': '2009-04-02',
     'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
     'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
     'Asset': 'A'
   }, {
     'Date': '2009-04-03',
     'Raw': Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
     'Raw2': Math.floor(Math.random() * 25),
     'Asset': 'A'
   }
   ]

   let counter = 0;
   // Push new data every 5 seconds for a specific date
   var h = setInterval(function () {
     if (counter < newdata.length) { // this limits the steps to only the length of the newdata
      data_set.push(newdata[counter]);
      counter++;
      drawGraph(data_set);
     }
   }, 3000);
   ```

[Working block here](https://bl.ocks.org/akulmehta/a265d4d8d455b8a313764fb79ff25757).

If however, you anticipate that the new data will come in for the same dates, you will have to update your `data_set` before calling `drawGraph` in your `setInterval` using the following:

```
    // Push new data every 5 seconds for a specific date
    var h = setInterval(function () {
      //obtain the index from the data_set for the same date
      let index = data_set.findIndex((f) => f.Date === newdata[counter].Date);
      if (index === -1) { // if data with same date not found push the new data
        data_set.push(newdata[counter]);
      } else { //else if it is found replace the old data
        data_set[index] = newdata[counter];
      }
      counter++;
      drawGraph(data_set);
    }, 3000);
```

[Working Block Here](https://bl.ocks.org/akulmehta/8e9c039a6ef82bc056fe416111da27c7). Note in this example, the `newdata` also contains some more data at the end for old dates. So you will see the lines jump up and down based on the new dates.